# Flickr API upload photo from URL

Tags: c#, upload, flickr

I have a website with photo gallery and I'd like to upload each photo (one by one) to my Flickr account. I managed to upload a photo from my local disk but is there a way to specify URL so that image is being picked from that URL and uploaded to Flickr?

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation (http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html and http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.example.html), the only means to do an upload is by placing the bytes of the image on the wire.  <strike>However, depending on your implementation language (your SO question tags don't specify one), there might be a library that could turn a URL into uploadable bytes for you.</strike>

**Update**

Flickr links to [FlickrNet](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/), which might have code that could turn a URL into uploadable bytes.  The documentation for the project looks sparse, but it is apparently being actively maintained by [Sam Judson](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/samjudson).

Comment: Thank you for answer. My language is C#. Any suggestion how could I do this?